# MySQL - Selecting DISTINCT field with other fields

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table..

```
field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4
data_1  | data_2  | data_3  | data_4
```

all the data withing tablename can potentially repeat.

I want to select unique field_1's so that i dont get any repeats, but I also need the rest of that row of data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4 FROM tablename;
```

The query above obviously does not work. So my question is how can i do this?

**Update**

How can I prevent the duplicates from displaying.

so if i have

```
data_1|data_2|data_3|data_4
data_1|data_2|data_3|data_4
data_6|data_7|data_8|data_9
```

the results will only display

```
data_6|data_7|data_8|data_9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you give more records? The query below will produce unique `field_1` but a random record for every group (*especially when dealing with large database*).

```
SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY field_1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1717e/1)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Ok, i feel stupid because i always assumed group by would do just that... group things together. Why does it remove repeats?

Comment: because it groups `field_1` and by that it will only show unique `field_1`.

Comment: `ORDER BY` groups stuff together as you put it.  `GROUP BY` controls summary queries.

Comment: @OllieJones what do you mean by *`ORDER BY` groups stuff together as you put it.*? -- maybe you mean `sort`.

Comment: ACTUALLY, how can remove all DUPLICATES. SO if 2 identical entries exist... dont show either of them?

Comment: Exactly, JW. I've seen lots of people who don't know sql lingo understand `group by` to mean sorting

Comment: @JW, this works. I understand how the HAVING COUNT(*)=1 works. Can you explain why this time there was a need to group by all fields instead of just the important one?

Comment: @ipixel because it will only count as duplicate if all columns from the rows have the same data. if you only put one column on the group by clause and on of the column's value iis different from the other rows column then it may be considered as another group.